# requests.get not giving any response

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm new with this whole requests stuff. I tried to get the response from an url and I there were some few times in which I was able to. However, after several tries and adding new lines of code, it stopped working.
This is the part of my code where I'm having trouble:

```
api_request = requests.get("https://www.airnowapi.org/aq/observation/zipCode/current/?format=application/json&zipCode=12345&distance=5&API_KEY=1234-1234-1234-1234")
    api = json.loads(api_request.content)
    city = api[0]["Reporting Area"]
```

it tells me that the variable city is not defined, therefore it follows that the requests.get() part has been unsuccessful.
I read some other people who had the same problem, but theirs had something to do with Headers (I tried copying the solutions but they didn't seem to work). I also tried copying the url on google and it opened the json file correctly, so it's a Python problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe remove the space of the key **"Reporting Area"** so that it is **"ReportingArea"** instead.

Comment: You should look at what `api` is and you will see you need: `city = api[0]["ReportingArea"]`

Comment: Have you checked manually querying that URL? Perhaps it has errors. Based on your code, you always just assume that the response from the URL would be a list of dict containing `"Reporting Area"`, but what if the URL resulted to a 500 server error?

Comment: This code will generate an `IndentationError`. Are the second and third lines supposed to be lined up with the first? Please read [ask]. We can't be expected to guess which errors are relevant and which are typos.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but wanted to warn you that you accidentally leaked your API key. If you don't want others to exploit it, try to keep it private as much as possible ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
api_request = requests.get("https://www.airnowapi.org/aq/observation/zipCode/current/?format=application/json&zipCode=89129&distance=5&API_KEY=1369737F-5361-4CCC-B7C1-F52625548A41")
api = api_request.json()
city = api[0]["ReportingArea"]
```